# Pulling all entries

Tags: craft2

I'm having trouble trying to display all entries in my list.

This code is working fine to grab the first entry.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('positions') %}
    <li class="list-item-career tooltip">
        <div class="list-item__title" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
            <div class="col-6">{{ entry.title }}</div>
            <div class="col-6">{{ entry.locationLink.first }}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

If I change `.first` to `.last` I get the last one just fine as well, so `.last` works.

If I change to `.all()`,  I get the error:

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string.

When I change to `entry.locationLink.find()`, I get this error:

> Array to string conversion

Can someone please help me figure out what I must do to give my complete list of 5 to display?

Thank you in advance for any light someone can provide.

Comment: What type of field is `locationLink`? And what version of Craft are you running?

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting back to me,. I have a page I made for jobs,. and I list the job positions and then what cities have a opening. In this case I have a field called:  Location Link, and its handle is  "locationLink" 

Then in my Entries I have "job positions" where I can add the locations.  Here I can add up to 5 (what I set it for). Then on my jobs page it shows postions and citys..

Currently it is only showing the first ciyt or last one in the list if I change my code to .last. I just cant seem to get them all to list :(

Comment: Im using Craft 2.9.2

Comment: I also have a entry section called locations when I added all the cities.

Comment: Craft v2 is no longer supported, I'd suggest you update to at least v3, ideally v4.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

Im new to craft so I was not 100% sure what needed to be done but I figured out I needed to make a loop because the array.

This is what I changed:
I changed this part {{ entry.locationLink.first }}

To:        {% for location in entry.locationLink %} {{ location.title }}

That listed all my locations, then I added below to comma separate them.

```
       {% if loop.last == false  %},{% endif%} {{item}}
       
       {% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps others. Thanks Brad for trying.